# How to map one-to-many relationship using C# code mapping?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

`Account.cs`

```
public IList<Alert> Alerts { get; set; }
```

`Alert.cs`

```
public Account Account { get; set; }

Bag<Alert>(x => x.Alerts, c => { }, r => { r.OneToMany(); });
```

and on the alert side

`AlertMap.cs`

```
ManyToOne(x => x.Account);
```

Can someone confirm that this mapping is correct?

Comment: Are you using `Fluent`. If no, what library are you using for mapping?

Comment: not using fluent. mapping by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- when you have a backreference as in your example the onetomany mapping should have `Inverse()` set
- it is better to specify the keycolumn on both sides explicitly to avoid creating 2 different foreign keys
- consider setting cascading to something other than none to enable cascading save/update/delete
- if Alerts can't stand on their own (without an Account) add Cascade.DeleteOrphan

`Bag(x => x.Alerts, c => { c.Inverse(); c.Key("account_id"); }, r => { r.OneToMany();`});

`ManyToOne(x => x.Account, c => c.Column("account_id"));`

Note:

- the generic argument can be infered by the compiler
- this is of the top of my head, the syntax may differ